# Linq sort by products but display cateogires

Tags: linq, list, sorting, product

So I have an issue where the code is Selecting a Category
and I need to change sort order to sort by product.Name Then By category.name.

But the problem is I still want to select a category, but how do I 
sort by product.name first without adding an extra join or select.

from category in categories
   select category.name 
   orderby category.Name    //orderby category name

Later on in view I loop  foreach(category.products) and pass in category.product[i] to view to display

But sort order is wrong, order is always by Category.Name
How do I sort by Product.Name first and then by Category.Name?
Will SelectMany help? Again I do not want to disrupt the select 
part of my query, just the Order by stuff.

class Product
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
}

class Category
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }
}

// Specify the first data source.
static List categories = new List()
{ 
    new Category(){Name="Beverages", ID=001},
    new Category(){ Name="Condiments", ID=002},
    new Category(){ Name="Vegetables", ID=003},
    new Category() {  Name="Grains", ID=004},
    new Category() {  Name="Fruit", ID=005}
};

// Specify the second data source.
static List products = new List()
{
    new Product{Name="Cola",  CategoryID=001},
    new Product{Name="Tea",  CategoryID=001},
    new Product{Name="Mustard", CategoryID=002},
    new Product{Name="Pickles", CategoryID=002},
    new Product{Name="Carrots", CategoryID=003},
    new Product{Name="Bok Choy", CategoryID=003},
    new Product{Name="Peaches", CategoryID=005},
    new Product{Name="Melons", CategoryID=005},
};

Comment: sorry I can't post the comment but I made a mistake

Comment: class Category { List<Proudcts> products;  public string Name { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; } }

Comment: Sorry I should have said Categories has a list or products. Perhaps a property in the class.

Comment: Here is the revised code, you can pump into LInqPad4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Category
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public List<Product> products { get; set;}
}

class Product 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }
}


void Main()
{
        // Specify the second data source.
         List<Product> BevProducts = new List<Product>()
        {
            new Product{Name="ZCola"},
        };

        // Specify the third data source.
         List<Product> CondProducts = new List<Product>()
        {
            new Product{Name="Sugar"},
        };
      // Specify the first data source.
     List<Category> categories = new List<Category>()
        { 
            new Category(){Name="Beverages", ID=001, products=BevProducts},
            new Category(){ Name="Condiments", ID=002, products=CondProducts},

        };



        var sortedCats = categories.OrderBy(c => c.products.Min(p => p.Name)).ToList();

        foreach (var category in sortedCats)
        {
            //display category
            System.Console.Out.WriteLine(category.Name);


            //Assuming each category contains exactly one product in the list ie 1 to 1 relationship
            // how can I sort by product.Name, so if ZCola comes before Sugar, ZCola's Category (Beverages) sorts before Condiments
            // so in this Case Beverages, Condiments is the right order, because ZCola comes after Sugar.
            var  sortedProductsPerCategory = category.products.OrderBy(p => p.Name).ToList();

            foreach (var product in sortedProductsPerCategory)
            {
                    //display product
                    System.Console.Out.WriteLine("   " + product.Name);
            }
        }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I saw you query, it was badly formatted.

You need to `order by Product.Name group by Category.Name`

Answer (score 0):

```
//LinqPad code

class Category
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public List<Product> products { get; set;}
}

class Product 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }
}


void Main()
{
        // Specify the second data source.
         List<Product> BevProducts = new List<Product>()
        {
            new Product{Name="ZCola"},
        };

        // Specify the third data source.
         List<Product> CondProducts = new List<Product>()
        {
            new Product{Name="Sugar"},
        };
      // Specify the first data source.
     List<Category> categories = new List<Category>()
        { 
            new Category(){Name="Beverages", ID=001, products=BevProducts},
            new Category(){ Name="Condiments", ID=002, products=CondProducts},

        };



        var sortedCats = categories.OrderBy(c => c.ID).ToList();

        foreach (var category in sortedCats)
        {
            //display category
            System.Console.Out.WriteLine(category.Name);

        //Assuming each category contains exactly one product in the list ie 1 to 1 relationship
// how can I sort by product.Name, so if ZCola comes before Sugar, ZCola's Category (Beverages) sorts before Condiments
// so in this Case Beverages, Condiments is the right order, because ZCola comes after Sugar.
            var  sortedProductsPerCategory = category.products.OrderBy(p => p.Name).ToList();

            foreach (var product in sortedProductsPerCategory)
            {
                    //display product
                    System.Console.Out.WriteLine("   " + product.Name);
            }
        }



}
```

Comment: So the right order is Sugar, ZCola    But this prints ZCola, Sugar